# Remotely access your Android device using Python or API

Tags: python, android

Is there any app which can help me access my Android device remotely using some API or some Python package? Like I want to ring phone, get phone battery information and send messages. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

AirDroid allows you remote control with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how this isn't solved. I've been looking for a simple clean API to control my rooted pixel. Looked into Airdroid doesn't seem to quite fit the bill but surely there is SOMETHING! ill probably endup having to build a server-side app in flutter enabling root commands, and send them directly from a python  client. Really trying to avoid having to build that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35464511)